# It's necessary "demote" an old PDC?

Tags: samba, active-directory

Hello: in my work there is an Active Directory mounted in Samba 4.1.7 (Debian Wheezy), I did not know much about the topic so I started studying and recently added a secondary Domain Controller, which runs on Samba 4.6.3 (Debian Jessie).
I have done tests in a virtual environment (VirtualBox) recreating the most possibly exact conditions of the real situation and removing the old server (4.1.7) and leaving only the newest connected (4.6.3) all the users can continue working without apparent problems... now is the question:

To leave only the secondary (4.6.3) as a Primary Domain Controller, I
have to do the "demote" of the oldest (4.1.7)? Or simply by
disconnecting the oldest one (4.1.7) from the network he will assume
the roll of Primary?
Greetings!

Comment: you already answered your question by `simply by disconnecting the oldest one (4.1.7) from the network he will assume the roll of Primary`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer...I only need a confirmation to my doubt even if I make the virtual tests...thanks :-)